# Can I update an Android manifest xml file via a GooglePlay update

Tags: android, android-manifest, updates

I have an app on GooglePlay. One of my friends purchased it, and found that it crashed when making an activity transition. I found the problem; it was in the manifest xml file. I changed it, and sent out an update. My friends install of my app still crashes. The alteration should have fixed the problem, but it didn't, and I suspect that its due to the inability to alter the manifest file outside of my IDE. Another issue with this is that the app ran fine on my Nexus 7, and another friends GS3 BEFORE the update! The negatively affected device I've referenced is an LG G2X. Whats going on here???

//This is the java file for the activity that launches the intent that causes the crash

```
@TargetApi(14)
public class CashButtonSignal1 extends Activity {

TextView cashButton1SignalText;
Timer timer1 = new Timer();
boolean b1 = true;
TimerTask timerStep1;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_cash_button_signal1);

setupActionBar();

}

/**
* Set up the {@link android.app.ActionBar}, if the API is available.
 */
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
private void setupActionBar() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}


    cashButton1SignalText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.cashButton1SignalText);

    timerStep1 = new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                  @Override
                  public void run() {
                if (b1) {
                    cashButton1SignalText.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                    cashButton1SignalText.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                    b1=false;
                } else {
                    cashButton1SignalText.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                    cashButton1SignalText.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                    b1=true;
                }
                }
            });
        }
};

timer1.schedule(timerStep1,200,200);

}


public void cashButton1SignalTextClicked (View cashButton1SignalTextClickedView){

    Intent displayCashOrderActivity = new Intent (this, CashOrderActivity.class);
    startActivity(displayCashOrderActivity);

}
```

//This is the activity's xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/cashButton1SignalText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:textColor="#FF0000"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="230sp"
    android:text="@string/orderSignalText"
    android:onClick="cashButton1SignalTextClicked" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everytime you update your app in google play you send a new `apk` which is a complete installation package that doesn't know anything about the device it is going to be installed on.

So it is possible to send an update to google paly with only changes in manifest file or a resource or no change at all !.

What is going on, it seems like you are getting an exception on that activity start on that device. most likely you have a conflict in your Layout files (maybe messing views or ID conflict).

Double check your alternative resources and run your app on multiple emulators with multiple screen sizes and hopefully you find the bug.

**Edit**: there might be some limits on the updated package in the google play system it self. what I'm sure of is that the app version number should increment in each update.

Comment: The app runs perfectly on every emulator I've used, as well as my actual device, the nexus 7. It was working fine before I found a problem in the title of one of my manifest xml, parent activity declarations. So you're right, it was one of my ID's; but the update should have fixed this, right? How can it work fine on some devices, without throwing an exception, and crash in others?

Comment: I've done so, and it all works. Could having an API import in an activity that a user's device has not upgraded to, cause this kind of crash? I've noticed that some activities required me to import certain API's, and not the same one in all; maybe this is the cause, what do u think?

Comment: I have added the code you requested.All of my java files have api 14 as the target. Should I change this to the target api I have in my manifest (17). If so, is there a certain way to do this other than just manual input?

Comment: The java code seems to be fine and the target API is irreleivent for the carsh because the device is running API 10 or 9. make sure you only have one layout file named 'activity_cash_button_signal1' if that is the case then you will need a stacktrace from the crash to see what is going on

Comment: I figured it out. My friend is running 2.3.4; my layout files are tagged with the sw<>dp attribute which is only compatible with 3.2 and above; I haven't included the old qualifiers "normal" and "large", and thats why its crashing. It looks like I'll have to set my minimum sdk to 13. Thanks for your help Mr.Me!